# Solution to $y(x) + y'(x) + y''(x) + y'''(x) + \cdots = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a non-trivial solution to the following differential equation?

$$y(x) + y'(x) + y''(x) + y'''(x) + \cdots= 0$$

That is, is there a smooth function $y : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $x$, the series
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{d^n y}{dx^n}(x)$$
converges to zero.

Comment: Suppose you can give a meaning to the infinite sum and a solution exists; if differentiating term by term is possible, then $(y+y'+\dotsb)'=0$, so $y=0$.

Comment: @egreg : Maybe your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, I'm waiting for the OP to state the problem more precisely.

Comment: How about $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^{(n)}(x)=\text{some nonzero function}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Maybe the question of how to make it precise should come later.  Dirac didn't make his delta function and its derivatives precise.  Cardano didn't make imaginary numbers precise.

Comment: Just a thought but if $y=\sin(x)$, every $4^{th}$ partial sum would be $0$. Or if $y=\exp(-x)$, every even partial sum would be $0$.

Comment: Yep, I'm realising now the question is not very well posed. What I'm trying to ask, is if there is a function $y$ such that for each $x$, the series converges to zero. I'll edit the question to reflect what I mean.

Comment: @oliveeuler:  for convergence you need all the partial sums to converge.  For $\exp (-x)$ the sums are $\exp (-x), 0,\exp (-x), 0,\exp (-x), 0 \dots$ which does not converge.  I was working on the same idea.

Comment: My first attempt was to assume that a solution existed as a power series: $y = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$
The differential equation then places constraints on the coefficients, namely: $a_n + (n+1)a_{n+1} + (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} + (n+3)(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+3} + \cdots = 0$, but I was stuck from there since I wasn't able to find coefficients satisfying that condition.

Comment: @egreg:  Shouldn't the right side of your equation be $-y$, and not $0$?

Comment: @WillO $y+y'+\dotsb=0$; differentiate: $y'+y''+\dotsb=0$; substitute: $y=0$.

Comment: @egreg:  d'oh!  You're right, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no non-trivial real analytic solution.

Indeed, if
$$
y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n x^n}{n!},
$$
then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^{(n)}(x)=0$, implies that $\sum_{n\ge k}a_n=0$, for all $k\ge 0$,
and hence $a_n=0$, for all $n\ge 0$.

Comment: This does not preclude the existence of smooth solutions, though.

Answer (score 2):

The previous solution is the solution for the equation $y+y'+\ldots+y^{(n)}=0$. 
But for this equation you  can compose with the operator $I-D$ where $D$ is the operator $D(y)=y'$, your equation write $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}D^{(n)}(y)=0$, then $(I-D)\circ (\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}D^{(n)})(y)=I(y)=y=0$

Answer (score 1):

$t\mapsto \sum_{\lambda\in \Gamma}\alpha e^{\lambda t}$ where $\Gamma$ is the set of solutions of the characteristic equation $1+x+x^2+x^2+\ldots=0$, and $\alpha\in \mathbb{K}$

Comment: There are no solutions to this equation though, $1+x + x^2 + \ldots$ converges only if $\| x \| < 1$ in which case the sum equals $\frac{1}{1-x} \neq 0$ for any $x$

Comment: I confused this equation with the equation $1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n=0$

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there is no solution to your equation.

There *are*, however, solutions to the closely related equation

$$(y(x)+y'(x))+(y''(x)+y'''(x))+\ldots =0$$

Namely:  $y=Ae^{-x}$ ($A$ constant).